# How to design Model class in iOS application (following MVC pattern)

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am going to start developing a new iOS application and planning to implement MVC pattern. Below is my understanding so far on Model, view and controller.

**View**- responsible to display user interface (e.g. xib file etc...)

**controller**- this will be the bridge between model and view. We can consider view controllers under this category. Also, we can write a subclass of NSObject to do network operations (using NSURLConnection).

**Model**- I understand that it's responsible for storing the data which will be displayed in the view. But, how does it store it? Is it going to be singleton class or it should be a normal subclass of NSObject with a custom init method? But, how will it persist the data? If someone can explain this with a clear example, it will be really helpful. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: avoid singletons if you can.  You have a number of options for persistence - Core Data, sqlite, Parse.com

Comment: [THIS](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-modelviewcontroller-mvc-design-pattern.html), [THIS](http://codewithchris.com/how-to-make-iphone-apps-mvc-one-pattern-to-rule-them-all/), [THIS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) all explain the MVC pattern, apart from countless other articles on the web. IMHO, the best way to understand is to begin implementing (some might differ). Head over to the articles, and proceed step by step. You'l get the hang of it, **in time**

Comment: This link has some useful stuffs like designing model class for local data and server data and also mistakes done while doing it , http://angelolloqui.com/blog/27-MVC-in-Objective-C-II-Model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **model represents the data that your app is operating with**. It doesn't necessarily have to do anything with *data persistence*.

In general, you have to think about the kinds of objects that are playing a role in your application. Let's assume a simple *To-Do-List*-app for that matter. In this kind of app, your **model** most likely will contain a *class* for a *Task* (or some similar concept). In Objective-C, you can then go an create the class, adding some properties that make sense. In its most basic and simple version, this could look like this:

```
@interface Task : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic        ) BOOL done;
@end
```

Then, at runtime you can instantiate this class in order to do something with the resulting objects. E.g. a user could be able to mark a *task* as `done`.

These objects will live in a certain memory area of the OS, called the *heap*. Data that lives on the heap, is not persisted. In order to persist data, you will have to use data persistence frameworks, such as `Core Data`, `Realm` or raw `SQLite`.

Also, using singletons for your model classes doesn't make a lot sense, since you usually want to instantiate multiple objects of them. A singleton on the other hand is characterised by the fact that it is instantiated *exactly once* during the lifetime of your app. This is contradictory with the purpose of the model layer.

Comment: Thanks!!  So,  when I get the data from my remote server,  it will be in Json format.  So,  I will need to convert  them into the properties of my model class according to my requirements.  Then I can pass on that model object or array of model objects to the view controller to display it in ui.  Is it correct understanding???

Comment: yes! that's absolutely how you have to do it! :) parse your json and store its content in your model objects and then use those model objects within your controller to (eventually modify them and) display the properties on the view

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick is your question answered or do you need more help? :)

Answer (score 2):

MVC typically does not have any relation to the Data-Access-Layer or external services. To recap the MVC pattern is as such:

**Model** Is responsible for delivering data to the *instance* of the View.

**Controller** Is responsible for delivering the *appropriate* UI view.

**View** Is responsible for delivering the UI (user interface).

Reviewing this shows us that any MVC pattern is specifically designed to control the flow and UI of the application. MVC patterns do not take into consideration any other aspect such as:

1. Data Access (storage, management etc)
2. Business Logic
3. Remote services
4. etc....

Speaking generally lets assume you follow an MVC pattern you still need to create your own classes (call them services) to interact with your external systems.

For your model classes they are not typically a singleton and are constructed as needed. They should provide enough information to the owning object to allow for communication to other application layers without the need for the owning object to understand or implement the model services.

Comment: Actually I don't want to persist the data. I will be connecting to a remote server for Json data.  Then I need to display it on the user interface and also few business manipulation on that data.

Comment: This is also correct answer!! But, I had already marked the other answer as correct.